# Checking if element doesn't contain specific sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to check if an element doesn't contain a specific sentence.

```
<div id="element">Hey there, This is the element I want to check if it doesn't contain specific text</div>

<script>

    var element = document.getElementById('element');

    if( element.textContent == 'hello world' < 0 ){
        console.log('The element doesn't contain this sentence');
    }else{
        console.log('The element contain this sentence');
    }

</script>
```

So if the element with id `element` doesn't contain `hello world`, I if statement should be executed. And if the element contains the text `hello world` the else statement should be executed.

This should also work if I check a sentence that does exist like `Hey there`, Then the else statement should be executed.

Comment: You are looking for the [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) property.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition:

```
element.textContent == 'hello world'
```

doesn't test if the text contains the text. It tests if it equals the text.

A better test would be:

```
element.textContent.includes('hello world')
```

However since includes isn't supported on IE and polyfills for this is unneccesary we can use indexOf:

```
element.textContent.indexOf('hello world') > -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `includes()` to check for possible match.

```js
let str = 'hello world';
console.log(str.includes('hello world'));
console.log(str.includes('hello worlds'));
```

Answer (score 0):

indexOf is your friend.

Here is your code changed a little

```
<div id="element">Hey there, This is the element I want to check if it doesn't contain specific text</div>

<script>

    var element = document.getElementById('element');

    if( element.textContent.indexOf('hello world') < 0 ){
        console.log("The element doesn't contain this sentence");
    }else{
        console.log('The element contain this sentence');
    }

</script>
```